# Python Beautifulsoup access text in tags?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am having trouble finding and returning the value that appears to be in the `<b>` tag, I have no luck when reading any of the tags.

I don't want to post a hundred lines of the view-source info and am not sure how to properly post the link to it but here is the webpage if you would be able to view the page source yourself http://yugiohprices.com/card_price?name=Dark+Magician

the information I am trying to retrieve
https://postimg.org/image/5fwxfqjqf/

Here is the code I am using

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get('http://yugiohprices.com/card_price?name=Dark+Magician'); 
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
print soup.find('b').text
```

this is the output

Home 
| Top 100 | Browse Cards | Browse Sets

Purchase Statistics
                      | Watchlist | Card Pricer

Sell My Cards | Price Alerts | Blog | FAQ | Settings

No matter what I change or try I am unable to access the "LDK2-ENY10" text

Comment: This is my first post so be gentle, and let me know what information I can add if any to help you help me :)

Comment: Please review [ask] and, more specifically, [mcve]. As suggested there, please provide a short, complete, self-contained program that demonstrates the problem. In your case, you don't need `requests` to demonstrate the problem, but you do need a short HTML snippet, the expected output, and the actual output of your program.

Comment: It is likely that the string you seek is not actually in the HTML. It is likely that the string is later inserted by Javascript code, probably using AJAX. Please provide the URL so that someone can confirm this.

Comment: Replace print soup.find(b) with print soup.find(b).text. This will print the text within the first occurrence of the b tag.

Comment: Instead of posting images of code, or links to images of code, post the code. And get the code by using the "view source" option in the browser or by saving the file. What you see in the "inspect" view is not the actual source.

Comment: how would i post the page source properly? its quite long and trying to post a link to it doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the page takes a while to load the data, the data is requested through an Ajax request so what requests returns is not what you see in your browser. You can mimic the ajax request with a simple get to http://yugiohprices.com/get_card_prices/Dark+Magician, passing a *timestamp*:

```
import requests
from time import time

r = requests.get("http://yugiohprices.com/get_card_prices/Dark+Magician?_={}".format(int(time())))

print(r.content)
```

That you will see gives you all the details about the card, so to get what you want just find the *anchor* with the *href* starting with */browse_sets?set*:

```
In [1]: import requests
   ...: from time import time
   ...: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   ...: 
   ...: r = requests.get("http://yugiohprices.com/get_card_prices/Dark+Magician?
   ...: _={}".format(int(time())))
   ...: soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
   ...: print(soup.select_one("a[href^=/browse_sets?set]").text)
   ...: 
Legendary Decks II

In [2]:
```

Comment: Sorry it took so long to mark it as resolved.. I'm still learning >.<